# Need to Open Two URL while clicking product view page button in grid mode?

Tags: admin, javascript, grid, magento-community

Need to Open Two URL while clicking product view page button in grid mode, Basically its a coupon site. In Grid mode when clicking the product view page button. It has to open product page url & coupon site url. Am facing an error. When clicking the button, It opens the product page of last product in the grid view.

The Code i used is`

```
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" 
                        onclick="openWindow()"><span><span><?php echo $_product->getCouponCodeUse(); ?></span></span></button></p>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow() {
var popup = window.open("<?php echo $_product->getCouponUrlValue() ?>","_self");
            window.open("<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>","window1");

}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Next to each button you **redefine** the function "openWindow" (in the global namespace). You could use a different name each time, or better, use [`Event.observe()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/) instead of "onclick".

2.) You should probably open the popup in `window1` before opening a new page in the same window (`_self`), this seems to stop the JS processing immediately.

Comment: hi fschmengler, Thanks for your reply, Am totally new to magento and not good in js. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: This is not really a Magento specific problem. Check out the linked documentation of `Event.observe` and try to write a "click" observer for each button (by the way, you must use a different `id` attribute for the button each time). Come back, when you tried it and are struggling with specific code that you have written.